# Class 'Inline\PDF\PDF' not found in laravel using wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf package

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use this package -> http://packalyst.com/packages/package/wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf

I have installed and configured as per the website and also I had used this package couple of times which worked following the same procedure.

But now its giving the error **Class 'Inline\PDF\PDF' not found**

Not sure whats the mistake.

Can someone please help me sort this issue.

Below is the sample code

**Composer.json file**

```
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.3",
"wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf": "1.0.*"
```

**app.php file**

```
'providers' => [
        //  other providers
        Inline\LaravelPDF\PDFServiceProvider::class
    ],

'aliases' => [
        // other aliases
        'PDF' => Inline\LaravelPDF\PDFFacade::class,

    ],
```

**In config/laravelpdf.php file**

```
<?php
return [
    'executable' => base_path().'/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386'
];
```

**`PHP Pdf code`**

```
use Inline\LaravelPDF\PDFFacade as PDF;

class SummaryHelper
{
   public function getReport($date)
   {
      // Some code
      $data = [ ];   // some data in it

      $pdf_obj = PDF::loadView('vendor/daily-report', $data);
   }
}
```

[Github issue link](https://github.com/wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf/issues/14)

[image: config/app.php file]

Comment: Try to replace `use Inline\LaravelPDF\PDFFacade as PDF;` for `use PDF;`

Comment: Run  `php artisan cache:clear` + `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @Troyer still getting the same error -> FatalErrorException in PDF.php line 7:
Class 'Inline\PDF\PDF' not found

Comment: @Troyer i used **use PDF;** and also the 2 commands you mentioned. But still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this.

I have changed the namespace to `Novanti` instead of `Inline`.

Please switch to `1.1.*` version and change `alias` and `provider` namespaces to `Novanti`.

I have also updated the `README.md` to better document this.

Let me know if this works.

Thank you for reporting.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed the package and got the same error. The thing is it's just a fork from another package and the guy didn't updated `readme.md` for correct namespaces. What you need to do it to change `Inline` to `Novanti` in `config/app.php`. Both for service provider and facade.

Then add this to the class where you want to use `PDF` facade:

```
use PDF;
```

Or just use full namespace:

```
$pdf_obj = \PDF::loadView('vendor/daily-report', $data);
```

Comment: if i use "use Inline\LaravelPDF\PDF\Facade as PDF;" i get the error as Class 'Inline\LaravelPDF\PDF\Facade' not found

Comment: if i use "use PDF;" i get the error has FatalErrorException in PDF.php line 7:  Class 'Inline\PDF\PDF' not found

Comment: after running composer du command i tried all the above approaches you mentioned but still error

Comment: when i change Inline to Novanti it says **undefined namespace LaravelPDF**

Comment: https://github.com/wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf/commit/126384ac844fcb8497c74554a8af46c841ab3c66

Comment: This works for me: `'PDF' => Novanti\LaravelPDF\PDFFacade::class,` and `Novanti\LaravelPDF\PDFServiceProvider::class` - try to change an alias and service provider record to these and run `composer du`

Comment: i have posted an image in original post with the same code what you have mentioned but gives the same error. If you see the first and last line its highlighted with red color

Comment: @Sharath did you change `compose.json`? I'm talking about the 7th comment.

Comment: what should i change in composer.json file

Comment: @Sharath nothing. 7th comment shows some changes in `composer.json`. If you didn't change it, it should work. It works for me.